# Change row color based on a value (inside the row)

Tags: css, extjs, grid, row

I have this grid

```
{
        xtype: 'gridpanel',
        id: 'grdSeguimiento',
        margin: '20 0 10 0',
        width: 1423,
        store: 'Solicitud',
        viewConfig: {
            getRowClass: function(record, rowIndex, rowParams, store) {
                console.log(record);
                return record.data.get('TIEMPO') == 1 ? 'child-row' : 'adult-row';

            },
            stripeRows: false
        },
        columns: [

            {
                xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                hidden: true,
                dataIndex: 'TIEMPO',
                hideable: false
            }
        ],
        plugins: [
            {
                ptype: 'rowediting',
                listeners: {
                    edit: 'onRowEditingEdit'
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

And this css file

```
.child-row .x-grid-cell { 
background-color: #ffe2e2 !important; 
color: #900; 
} 

.adult-row .x-grid-cell { 
background-color: #e2ffe2 !important; 
color: #090;
 }
```

I just want each row to have a color based on a value (TIEMPO) inside each row.

But I am getting the

```
Error: rendered block refreshed at 0 rows while BufferedRenderer view size is 63
```

The grid worked fine before using the css file. I made some research but couldn't find anything useful.

The code above is not all the code, I used renderer and action columns but I gues that is not so important.

Any ideas?

**Edit 1**: If I change the table to non sortable the data appears but without any styling

Comment: `record.data.get('TIEMPO')` won't work. You are searching for `record.get('TIEMPO')`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Any ideas?

You need to change in your current code instead of 
 this `record.data.get('TIEMPO')` you need to use `record.get('TIEMPO')` or `record.data.TIEMPO` for more details you can refer this Ext.data.Model [`get()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-method-get).

Here I have created an small [sencha fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/29hk) demo. You can see it is working fine here.

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId: 'simpsonsStore',
    fields: ['name', 'email', 'phone', 'isChecked'],
    data: {
        'items': [{
            'name': 'Lisa',
            "email": "lisa@simpsons.com",
            "phone": "555-111-1224",
            "isChecked": 1
        }, {
            'name': 'Bart',
            "email": "bart@simpsons.com",
            "phone": "555-222-1234",
            "isChecked": 0
        }, {
            'name': 'Homer',
            "email": "homer@simpsons.com",
            "phone": "555-222-1244",
            "isChecked": 0
        }, {
            'name': 'Marge',
            "email": "marge@simpsons.com",
            "phone": "555-222-1254",
            "isChecked": 1
        }]
    },
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'items'
        }
    }
});

Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Grid row class on basis for row value..',
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
    viewConfig: {
        getRowClass: function (record, rowIndex, rowParams, store) {
            return record.get('isChecked') == 1 ? 'child-row' : 'adult-row';
            //you can also use
            //record.data.isChecked == 1 ? 'child-row' : 'adult-row';

        },
        stripeRows: false
    },
    columns: [{
        text: 'Name',
        dataIndex: 'name',
        flex: 1
    }, {
        text: 'Email',
        dataIndex: 'email',
        flex: 1
    }, {
        text: 'Phone',
        dataIndex: 'phone',
        flex: 1
    }],
    height: 200,
    // width: 400,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked, I also forgot to add the link to the stylesheet in the html